# Using c++ dll in asp.net - Exception:Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c++, asp.net, .net, dll

I am using a already developed C++ dll in my asp.net code to make compression/decompression of the data. It works well on my developer machine and some other machines too. I have a client machine which is fresh(No fancy installation of various tools) and When it tries to call that dll it generates an exception.

Exception:`Could not load file or assembly 'dllcode, Version=1.0.5754.25819, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.`

I would like to know that which dependencies are missing on Client fresh machine?

Note: I am trying to call C++ dll in a windows service which is having asp.net 4.0 framework. This call is executing perfectly on my developer machine but generates above exception on my client machine.I do not have deep knowledge about c++ library and it's dll. From basic troubleshooting I tried to install various combinations of "microsoft visual c++ 2010 runtime" but it did not help.

**Update**: Somehow I find source code of this C++ dll and now I am trying to check if I can build this dll any version specific.

Comment: What's your target: any cpu, x86 or x64?

Comment: My target is any CPU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this resolved. What I did is, I had to create separate setups(32-Bit & 64-Bit). Also VC++ run time was needed on server. So I installed them and it worked.
Hope this help to any one if he faces the same issue.